# How to transform all non-zero values to a new column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, numeric

I have a dataframe with 81 columns and around 3000 rows. below is a sample df. I need to transform all non-zero value to a new column

```
    TO    Rubber    Wood    Plastic   Toy     Metal   Paper  Result
    AAA   0         0         0        0        0         9      1
    BBB   60        0         0        0        0         0     -1
    CCC   0         0.8       0        0        0         0      1
    DDD   0         0         0        40       0         0      1
    EEE   0         0         7        0        0         0      1
    FFF   0         0         0        0        10        0     -1
```

I have tried for transforming the column name to a new column,  but unable to do for values

```
     df['Mat'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:82] != 0).idxmax(1)
```

Result i need:

```
    TO    Rubber    Wood    Plastic   Toy     Metal   Paper  Result   WT    Mat
    AAA   0         0         0        0        0         9      1    60    Rubber
    BBB   60        0         0        0        0         0     -1 0.8      Wood
    CCC   0         0.8       0        0        0         0      1    7     Plastic
    DDD   0         0         0        40       0         0      1    40    Toy
    EEE   0         0         7        0        0         0      1    10    Metal
    FFF   0         0         0        0        10        0     -1    9      Paper
```

I would like to drop the unnecessary columns and then final result should be

```
    To       Wt        Mat

    AAA      60        Rubber
    BBB      0.8       Wood
    CCC      7         Plastic
    DDD      40        Toy
    EEE      10        Metal
    FFF      9         Paper
```

Comment: Seems data not matched - suurce with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all columns for found values with `sum`:

```
#1:7 by sample data, in real data seems 1:82
df['Wt'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:7]).sum(1)
df['Mat'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:82] != 0).idxmax(1)

#last select only necessary columns by list
df = df[['TO','Wt','Mat']]
print (df)
    TO    Wt      Mat
0  AAA   9.0    Paper
1  BBB  60.0   Rubber
2  CCC   0.8     Wood
3  DDD  40.0      Toy
4  EEE   7.0  Plastic
5  FFF  10.0    Metal
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df = df.set_index(['TO']).sum().reset_index()[:6].rename({'index':'Mat',0:'Wt'},axis=1).join(df['TO'])
##df[['TO','Wt','Mat']]

    TO    Wt      Mat
0  AAA  60.0   Rubber
1  BBB   0.8     Wood
2  CCC   7.0  Plastic
3  DDD  40.0      Toy
4  EEE  10.0    Metal
5  FFF   9.0    Paper
```

Comment: Excellent @iamklaus +1

Comment: @jezrael appreciate the feedback.. :) thats what first came to find